# Looking to parse and copy data for specific pattern in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to parse the following strings, where I want to copy the accession number in the beginning of the string to add after the "];" and before the "dxPhospho", please note that the number before the "x" can be any number and why I am calling it "d" here. This pattern of "**]; dPhospho**" is what I need to match.

```
# Sample dataframe
DT <- data.frame(Positions.in.Master.Proteins = c("Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]",
                                                  "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; 3xPhospho]"))
```

The output would look like this:

```
[1] "Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; Q8R149 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]"
[2] "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; Q9UET0 3xPhospho]"
```

Where you can now see that the accession numbers are copied to where I need them to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the package `gsubfn`, you can extract your accession number with `sub`, and treat it as the replacement directly.

```r
library(gsubfn)

unname(
  sapply(DT$Positions.in.Master.Proteins, 
         \(i) gsubfn(pattern = "; \\dxPhospho", 
                     replacement = \(x) paste0("; ", sub(" \\[.*", "", i)), 
                     x = i))
  )

[1] "Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; Q8R149 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]"
[2] "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; Q9UET0 3xPhospho]"
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
sapply(
  strsplit(DT$Positions.in.Master.Proteins, "];"),
  function(z) paste(c(z[1], paste(sub(" .*", "", z[1]), trimws(z[-1]))), 
                    collapse = "]; ")
)
# [1] "Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; Q8R149 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]" "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; Q9UET0 3xPhospho]"
```

- splitting solely on `;` is going to fail with the inner `;`, so we need to be more specific by using `strsplit(.., "];")`
- assuming that the string you need prepended to the second (and subsequent?) substrings contains no blank-space, we use `sub(" .*", "", ..)` to remove from the first space to the EOS for the first element, ...
- then prepend that leading portion to all except the first string, ...
- finally collapsing by `"]; "` to reform the original string
- the use of `trimws(.)` may be extraneous; in fact, some of this workflow is contingent on *always* seeing `];` and not `] ;` or `]  ;` or similar. If it is "always" `];`  (trailing space), then change the first `strsplit(.., "]; ")` and remove the `trimws`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer using only R `base` with capturing groups on regular expressions:

```
DT <- data.frame(Positions.in.Master.Proteins = c("Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]",
                                                  "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; 3xPhospho]"))
gsub("(\\w+)( .*\\]; )", "\\1\\2\\1 ", DT$Positions.in.Master.Proteins)
```

[1] "Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; Q8R149 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]"

[2] "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; Q9UET0 3xPhospho]"

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `str_replace` and a function as *replacement* argument

```
library(stringr)

with(DT, 
  str_replace(string = Positions.in.Master.Proteins, 
              pattern = "]; \\d+xPhospho", 
              replacement = sub("(^[[:alnum:]]+ \\d+xPhospho) .*", 
                                "]; \\1", Positions.in.Master.Proteins)))
[1] "Q8R149 2xPhospho [T131(100); T/S]; Q8R149 2xPhospho [T157(100); T/S]"
[2] "Q9UET0 3xPhospho [S23(90); T63(70); Y67(70)]; Q9UET0 3xPhospho]"
```